# Software available for singing "lessons" via computer microphone?

Tags: music, recording, voice

Looking for a software to help my friend learn to sing. Can't seem to find anything on googles.

Does there exist software (preferably downloadable and from this century!) that records one's voice and then analyzes it to see how "accurate" it was. It would be great if it also had some kind of "lessons" of some sort, and not simply sound recorder that shows waveforms.

I can't imagine it would be so hard to implement, and there probably is one out there - I just can't find it.

Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Canta is free, hooks up to your mic, and gives you notes to sing and shows how close you are. Pretty similar to Rock Band vocals, but a little more sophisticated.

http://www.singintune.org/

Some others are:

http://www.singandsee.com/forsingers.php

http://www.earpower.com/earpower.php